# How to show that the field of fractions of a domain $A$ is $\{ab^{-1}: a \in A, b \in A-\{0\}\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

Let $A$ be a domain. Suppose that for all $a,b\in A-\{0\}$, $Aa \cap Ab \neq \{0\}$ and $aA  \cap bA \neq \{0\}$. How to show that the field of fractions of $A$ is $\{ab^{-1}: a \in A, b \in A-\{0\}\}$?

The condition  $Aa \cap Ab \neq \{0\}$ is equivalent to the condition: there are some $a', b' \in A$ such that $ab^{-1}=b'^{-1}a'$.

The condition  $aA  \cap bA  \neq \{0\}$ is equivalent to the condition: there are some $a', b' \in A$ such that $b^{-1}a=a'b'^{-1}$.

Therefore 
$$
(a_1 b_1^{-1})(a_2 b_2^{-1}) = b_1'^{-1}a_1'a_2b_2^{-1} = (a_1'a_2)'b_1''^{-1}b_2^{-1} \in \{ab^{-1}: a \in A, b \in A-\{0\}\}.
$$
We have 
\begin{align}
& ab^{-1}+cd^{-1} \\
& = b'^{-1}a'+cd^{-1} \\
& = b'^{-1}(a'd+b'c)d^{-1} \\
&= (a'd+b'c)'b''^{-1}d^{-1} \in \{ab^{-1}: a \in A, b \in A-\{0\}\}.
\end{align}
Can we conclude that the field of fractions of $A$ is $\{ab^{-1}: a \in A, b \in A-\{0\}\}$? I think that we need both conditions $Aa \cap Ab \neq \{0\}$ and $aA  \cap bA \neq \{0\}$. Is it correct? Thank you very much.

Edit: here $A$ can be non-commutative.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you saying you're trying to prove the set satisfies the ring axioms? That is not conveyed very clearly by what you've said. Also, you should prefer "division ring of fractions" to "(noncommutative) field of fractions" in English to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by that notation, this is incorrect. The field of fractions does not consist of pairs $(a, b)$ such that $a \in A, b \in A \setminus \{ 0 \}$; it is a quotient of this set by a certain equivalence relation which you need to identify.

Comment: Ah, and I also misread your question; is $A$ not necessarily commutative?

Comment: For a commutative domain the Ore conditions are superfluous, and it would be a weird move to bring them up by coincidence, so it almost certainly is the noncommutative context.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, yes, $A$ is not necessarily commutative.